# How to combine Chrome.storage with chrome.WebRequest.onBeforeRequest listener?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to redirect some URLs according to user settings (saved in chrome.storage), with chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener().

I understand that storage operates async, but I can't wrap my head around how to combine it with the event listener, because both only accept one argument for their callback function and no others.  The listener only accepts the request object, and storage.sync.get only an object with the retreived data.

Since I can't return anything with the storage get function, how am I supposed to mix these two together?

I have tried putting the event listener inside the storage.sync.get callback function, also the other way around, I have tried several callback structures, but I'm out of ideas.

```
const urlfilter = {urls: "some_urls", types: ['main_frame', 'sub_frame']}
const opt_extraInfoSpec = ["blocking"];

chrome.storage.sync.get('somedata', function(data) {
  chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  (request) => { 
    if (data.somedata) {
      let query = data.somedata;        
      return {redirectUrl: request.url + query};         
    } 
  },  
    urlfilter,
    opt_extraInfoSpec
  );
});
```

This last example works, but only gets called once so does not respond when the storage changes. Also I don't know if this is even the right way to do it... All the solutions I've read here are for different use-cases of the storage.

Comment: Thank you, your answer in the other post is very precise and practical!